# Irregular Spacing Between List Items

Tags: css, html, listitem

Bear with me I am new at this

I have been faced with an issue of irregular spacing between list items, it looks like the image below. First, when I did not as many list items, it was normal, then once I exceeded a number, which I do not know it started showing spaces:
[image: picture of problem]

I played around with it some and apparently margins have nothing to do with it. Below are the HTML5 code and the CSS for the gallery and the list items. Here is my code:

## CSS

```
#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

## HTML

```
<ul id="gallery">
            <br>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Abraham Lincoln">
                <div id="al1930">
                    <img id="as1930" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie1.title, movie1.description, movie1.director, movie1.distributer, movie1.releasedate, movie1.link)" src="img/Abraham%20Lincoln%20Poster.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Abraham Lincoln</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Night of the Living Dead">

                <div id="nld1968">
                    <img id="nld1968" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie2.title, movie2.description, movie2.director, movie2.distributer, movie2.releasedate, movie2.link)" src="img/p3946_d_v8_ac.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Night of the Living Dead</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Africa Screams">
                <div id="as1949">
                    <img id="as1949" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie3.title, movie3.description, movie3.director, movie3.distributer, movie3.releasedate, movie3.link)" src="img/images.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Africa Screams</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Born To Win">
                <div id="btw1971">
                    <img id="btw1971" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie5.title, movie5.description, movie5.director, movie5.distributer, movie5.releasedate, movie5.link)" src="assets/Dvd_Born_to_Win.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Born to Win</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Meet John Doe">
                <div id="mjd1941">
                    <img id="mjd1941" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie6.title, movie6.description, movie6.director, movie6.distributer, movie6.releasedate, movie6.link)" src="assets/220px-Poster_-_Meet_John_Doe_01.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Meet John Doe</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Charade">
                <div id="c1963">
                    <img id="c1941" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie7.title, movie7.description, movie7.director, movie7.distributer, movie7.releasedate, movie7.link)" src="img/220px-Charade_movieposter.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Charade</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="The Terror">
                <div id="tt1963">
                    <img id="tt1963" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie8.title, movie8.description, movie8.director, movie8.distributer, movie8.releasedate, movie8.link)" src="img/the-terror.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>The Terror</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Angel and the Badman">
                <div id="ab1947">
                    <img id="ab1947" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie9.title, movie9.description, movie9.director, movie9.distributer, movie9.releasedate, movie9.link)" src="img/AngelandtheBadman.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Angel and the Badman</p>
                </center>
            </li>
            <li class="search-item" data-title="Rock, Rock, Rock!">
                <div id="rrr1956">
                    <img id="rrr1956" class="thumbs" onclick="transport(movie10.title, movie10.description, movie10.director, movie10.distributer, movie10.releasedate, movie10.link)" src="img/RockRockRock.gif" alt="">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <p>Rock, Rock, Rock!</p>
                </center>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: This is expected...the `li` are different heights I'd suggest a proper row/column grid system. Also `<center>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used. AND `<br`> tag shouldn't be used for spacing and are invalid HTML in a `ul`.

Comment: @Paulie_D is right. You might want to try [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to help with formatting... it makes CSS a lot easier.     :)

Comment: @yummypasta yes, I use BS for their amazing modals and carousels. Though I did not use BS for this use. Thanks PauIie did not use yours, though thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display inline block instead of float, check following css

```
#gallery {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0px; 
}
#gallery li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SuperUser it worked, though if you do not mind, can you explain your solution? Why should I use inline-block rather than float?

Comment: @HunchoDevelo As seen in this demo - https://jsfiddle.net/vxrnh8ww/1/ - this does not defeat the non equal height on the items, nor does it make any significant difference than the float does

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given each thumbnail a class try giving the thumb nails a class styling width and height so that they don't go beyond a fixed grid.

```
<style>
#thumbs
{
    max-width:150px;
    max-height:300px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but thanks for your contribution!